# Горизонтальное меню с наклонными разделителями

Tags: меню, html, css

Всем привет!

На одном форуме задавали вопрос по реализации такого меню
[image: img]

> Вопрос в том, как правильно вырезать картинку с разделителем при ховере(hover). Нужна именно картинка! Т.е. нужна кроссбраузерность, минимум от ie7.
>   При этом ширина пунктов меню не должна быть фиксированной.

Может кто делал уже такое? Что-то не догоню как реализовать такое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну реализовать это не сложно. Я накину обычным цветным бэкграундом, а вы уже подставляете картинки. Хотя и не по правилам сделано, но работает.

http://jsfiddle.net/DMPaL/1/

```
<a href='#'><p>текст</p><p>&nbsp;</p></a>

a {
  background: rgba(0,0, 150, 1);
  display: inline-block;
}
a p:first-child, a p:last-child   {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
  padding-right:10px;
}
a p:last-child {
  width: 10px;
  background: rgba(0,0, 200, 1);
  margin:0;
}

a:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 150, 0.5);
}
a:hover p:first-child {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
}

a:hover p:last-child   {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: О. Спасибо! Жаль в ie8 не работает.

Comment: @dropoff Видимо ie8 просто не понимает rgba.

Comment: ага. и проблемы какие-то с отступами. сейчас поковыряю еще.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ - использовать [image map](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp).
тогда у вас гарантированно будут правильные формы областей.
Разумеется, каждая кнопка состоит для универсальности, из трех частей.

Более сложный способ - [фигуры CSS3](http://www.css3shapes.com/). Но обратная совместимость никакая...

Comment: правильные формы областей не обязательно. Главное, чтобы было по максимуму кроссбраузерно и не сложно. За CSS3 фигуры спасибо! Но IE 7-8-9 нужную фигу(#parallelogram) почему-то не отрисовывае.

Comment: @dropoff, о том, как сделать кроссбраузерную трансформацию CSS3 - http://demos.aimweb.name/css-transform-generator/

Comment: Astor, не пашет у меня генератор. но тему понял. спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вот так

Используй прикрепленные рисунки, названий m1.png m2.png

http://postimage.org/image/ds8hvcsez/

http://postimage.org/image/xbd34pr6j/

> <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD
> HTML 4.01//EN"
> "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
> <html> <head> <meta
> http-equiv="Content-Type"
> content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
> <title>Документ без названия</title>
> </head>
>
> <style>
> *{margin:0;padding:0;} body {background:#333333;font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;}
> ul.menu {padding:0
> 20px;display:table;list-style:none;border-top:1px
> solid white;border-bottom:1px solid
> white;} ul.menu li
> {position:relative;background:
> url('images/m1.png') right
> center;float:left;margin-left:-15px;}
> ul.menu li a {display:table;
> position:relative;padding:0
> 20px;line-height:30px;color:white;text-decoration:none;}
> ul.menu li:hover {background:
> url('images/m2.png') right center;}
> ul.menu li a:hover {color:#333333;}
>
> </style>
>
> <body> <ul class="menu">   <li
> style="z-index:10;"> <a href="#"> home
> </a> </li>   <li style="z-index:9;">
> <a href="#">  services </a></li>   <li
> style="z-index:8;"> <a href="#"> 
> vacancies </a></li>   <li
> style="z-index:7;">  <a href="#"> chat
> </a></li>   <li style="z-index:6;"> <a
> href="#">  see other pages  </a></li> 
> </ul>
>
> </body> </html>

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x9HHq/ и где тут пример, который ТС хотел?

Comment: lampa, именно то, что хотел!
Сейчас поковыряю. А то делал на css3, а оно не везде работает правильно.

Comment: Правда с zindex не удобно.

Comment: А ты бек граунды подгрузи которые выше выложены и увидишь.

Comment: @Cone  Ну так сразу их давай :) http://jsfiddle.net/x9HHq/1/